# Fragment UI's using navigation drawer

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

So I have my navigation drawer functionality in the MainActivity of my project, and I have my nav drawer links linked to a fragment, but I don't know how to add a UI to that. Things specifically like findViewById(r.id.code), and trying to set TextView's give me errors like `unreachable code` here is what I have so far.

MainActivity

```
    package yc.android.yourchallenger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String [] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;    
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.nav_drawer, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);         
}

 @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);           
        }           
    }

 private void selectItem(int position) {
     Fragment fragment = null;

     switch (position){
     case 0: fragment = new CreateFragment();
     break;

     case 1: fragment = new ReadFragment();
     break;

     case 2: fragment = new HelpFragment();
     break;

     default:
         break;
     }
    /* Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putInt("key", position);
     fragment.setArguments(args);*/
    if(fragment != null){ 
         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                           .commit();
         // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
 }   

 @Override
 public void setTitle(CharSequence title){
     mTitle = title;
     getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
 }


}
```

And here is one of my fragments
        package yc.android.yourchallenger;

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ReadFragment extends Fragment {
public ReadFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
    TextView view = findViewById(R.id.view);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to make the view created in `onCreateView()` static (re: Droidy). Simply call `getView()` anywhere within the Fragment lifecycle after `onCreateView()`.

In your example, all you needed was to change

```
TextView view = findViewById(R.id.view);
```

to

```
TextView view = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view);
```

You can call `findViewById(int)` on any `ViewGroup` to find it's children. Calling it in an `Activity` is a convenience method that uses the view set in `setContentView()`.

So if you wanted to find the view later in the `Fragment` lifecycle, you'd do something like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.view);
}
```

You can also instantiate views in `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)`, where the root view is the first parameter.

Comment: I have stated, static within brackets, means it is optional. I am wondering whether you have answered the question or optimized my answer.

Comment: You should not make Views static, as it's likely to lead to a Context leak. There isn't any reason to make the root view a member variable. Static or not. Your answer shows that you were unaware of `getView()`, and you gave bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

Make `rootView` , `private` (`static`) and declare it before the default constructor. Then after inflating your layout to rootView, you can access all the UI elements by using the rootView as follows.

```
TextView view = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view);
```

Use `getActivity()`  instead of the keyword `this` inside your `Fragment` class.
Hope it helps.